# Dropdown value to select variable (variable variables)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown box which I use to select which table to display. The tables are string variables. I have tried to apply some of the examples dealing with variables variables but I'm not having any luck :-(.  [I've posted a simplified example here. http://jsfiddle.net/jamesm/mbmxL/](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesm/mbmxL/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var static_str = "This is the static table...";
   var pppoe_str = "This is the PPPoE table...";
   var dhcp_str = "This is the DHCP table...";
   $('#dropdown').change(function() {
       $("#seltxt").html($(this).val() + "_str" ) ;
   });
});


<form>
 <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
  <option value="0" >Choose</option>
  <option value="static" >Static</option>
  <option value="pppoe" >PPPoE</option>
  <option value="dhcp" >DHCP</option>
</select>
```

Seltext...

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can't convert a string into a variable name directly. In your case you can use the dictionary like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bS2vn/

P.S. I hope I understood you correctly, but your question is not clear. Next time try to ask explicitly what you have, what you want and what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
 <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
  <option value="0" >Choose</option>
  <option value="static" >Static</option>
  <option value="pppoe" >PPPoE</option>
  <option value="dhcp" >DHCP</option>
 </select>        
</form>

<div id="seltxt"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
   var str = new Object();
   str.static = "This is the static table...";
   str.pppoe = "This is the PPPoE table...";
   str.dhcp = "This is the DHCP table...";

   // Properties in javascript are just dictionaries in disguise, 
   // javascript is unique on that regard.
   // The above code could be rewritten as: 
   // str["static"] = "This is the static table";
   // str["pppoe"] = "This is the PPPoE table...";

   $('#dropdown').change(function() {
       $("#seltxt").html(str[ $(this).val() ]) ;
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DqdZN/

Another approach(use eval, a bad idea though, just structure your code like above):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var str = new Object();
   static_str = "This is the static table...";
   pppoe_str = "This is the PPPoE table...";
   dhcp_str = "This is the DHCP table...";
   $('#dropdown').change(function() {
       $("#seltxt").html( eval( $(this).val() + "_str" ) ) ;
   });
});
```